# Java/Android - setting float values - 0f vs 0.0f

Tags: java, android

I've been browsing through some Android source code and I noticed they set float values to `0` using `0.0f`. I know that just `0` is an `int` that is then implicitly converted to `float` and that `0.0` is a `double`, but to my knowledge `0f` is the same as `0.0f`. Why would they go through the effort to type the extra `.0` ? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no reason other than style. `0f` and `0.0f` are identical values. Details in [JLS§3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).